# Why is my Javascript ignoring the selected checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a script at the bottom of my page that contains multiple `datepickers`, `dropdownlists` of times and days.  I want to check value of the selected ones using a loop.  The problem is that the code only loops for the initial number of selected elements that was checked when the page loaded.  It will detect changes only to these initially selected elements.  It ignores any newly selected items.  Also, when I put the script at the top of the page it ignores any changes at all.

I've been trying different version of this code for about a week.  Can someone help me spot what may be my problem here?  Thanks for helping.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#date").datepicker();
        $('input[name=date]').datepicker();
        var dateInput = $("select[name='searchString']");

        var checkedindex = [];
        var classdate = [];
        var classtime = [];
        var dayofclass = [];
        var newDateAndTime = [];
        var oldDateAndTime = [];

        $("input[name='selectedCourses']").each(function (i) {
            if (this.checked) {
                checkedindex.push(parseInt(i));
            }
        });

        for (var x = 0; x < checkedindex.length; x++) {
            var ind = checkedindex[x];

            var dateofclass = $(".TextBoxDate:eq(" + ind + ")");
            var timeofclass = $(".TextBoxTime:eq(" + ind + ")");
            var classday = $("select[name='searchString']:eq(" + ind + ")");

            classdate.push(dateofclass);
            classtime.push(timeofclass);
            dayofclass.push(classday);

            oldDateAndTime = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();
        }

        $("#saveBtn").click(function () {

            for (var x = 0; x < checkedindex.length; x++) {
                var ind = checkedindex[x];

                var dateofclass = $(".TextBoxDate:eq(" + ind + ")");
                var timeofclass = $(".TextBoxTime:eq(" + ind + ")");
                var classday = $("select[name='searchString']:eq(" + ind + ")");

                classdate.push(dateofclass);
                classtime.push(timeofclass);
                dayofclass.push(classday);

                var testString = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();

                alert(testString + "  " + oldDateAndTime);

                oldDateAndTime = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fill the `checkedindex` array once the save button is clicked, otherwise it only contains the elements which were selected when the page is loaded. Try following script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#date").datepicker();
        $('input[name=date]').datepicker();
        var dateInput = $("select[name='searchString']");

        $("#saveBtn").click(function () {

            var checkedindex = [];
            var classdate = [];
            var classtime = [];
            var dayofclass = [];
            var newDateAndTime = [];
            var oldDateAndTime = [];

            $("input[name='selectedCourses']").each(function (i) {
                if (this.checked) {
                    checkedindex.push(parseInt(i));
                }
            });

            for (var x = 0; x < checkedindex.length; x++) {
                var ind = checkedindex[x];

                var dateofclass = $(".TextBoxDate:eq(" + ind + ")");
                var timeofclass = $(".TextBoxTime:eq(" + ind + ")");
                var classday = $("select[name='searchString']:eq(" + ind + ")");

                classdate.push(dateofclass);
                classtime.push(timeofclass);
                dayofclass.push(classday);

                var testString = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();

                alert(testString + "  " + oldDateAndTime);

                oldDateAndTime = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are computing `checkedindex` only once, at the start of the script. This array will only contain the checked checkboxes at the time that the script runs.

I assume that you want to iterate over the checked checkboxes whenever the #saveBtn element is clicked? If so, you need to re-computed the `checkedindex` array.

Be mindful of the selector that you are using, `input[name='selectedCourses']`. This restricts the `checkedindex` array to contain only checked checkboxes whose name attribute is equal to "selectedCourses".